# SubClass of UITableViewController and variable Initialization. iOS, SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, oop, cocoa-touch

I have a custom class, that subclass UITableViewController or UIViewController. And there I get a error, that every value should be inialized at super.init call. For me, the solution is to set a value for every property/variable, but why i just can't leave it just initializated, without any value? And what should I better do in that situation?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


class MSOrder: UITableViewController {
    var orderId: Int
    var orderNumber: Int
    var statusText: String


    init(orderId: Int,
         orderNumber: Int,
         statusText: String) {

            self.orderId = orderId
            self.orderNumber = orderNumber
            self.statusText = statusText

            super.init(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare your properties like this:

```
class YourViewController{
    var orderId: Int
    var orderNumber: Int
    var statusText: String
}
```

the controller expects them to contain a value after initialization, whereas if you do this:

```
class YourViewController{
    var orderId: Int!
    var orderNumber: Int!
    var statusText: String!
}
```

you tell the compiler that you'll ensure that those values will contain a value when you use them, bypassing the compile-time check. If you know what you are doing (and this is not that uncommon by the way) you can declare the variable types with a `!` suffix.

Another option would be to make those properties *optional*:

```
class YourViewController{
    var orderId: Int?
    var orderNumber: Int?
    var statusText: String?
}
```

That way, all the properties are allowed to be `nil`.

So when accessing those values you have to explicitly unwrap them:

```
self.statusText! // to get the unwrapped value of type String!
```

or

```
self.statusText?.somethingElse() // executes only if the statusText is set, otherwise continues execution of next lines
```

Values that have a `!` as part of their declaration can also be `nil`, but by specifying the `!` you ensure that it has a value when you access it without the need of explicit unwrapping.

```
let someValue : String!
```

So this would fail if the value is `nil`:

```
self.someValue // if someValue is nil, this will crash!
```

if you were to do this:

```
let someValue : String?
```

it would just carry on, because by specifying the optional `?` symbol, you say "Hey, I don't know for sure, but this value could be nil!"

Thus the need to unwrap it:

```
let iKnowThereIsAValueInSomeValue = self.someValue!
```

Let me know if something remains unclear.

Comment: So, I can use "!" suffix only if I 100% sure that everything will be okay and every variable gets its value, understood it. And the only way to make it safe is to set value right this:  var orderNumber: Int = 0 / var statusText: String = "" etc, right?

Comment: Well it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but let's imagine this scenario: You init the `TableViewController` and don't have the data yet (for example you'll set the properties in `viewDidLoad` or at some point after your initialization), then you'll have to declare your properties with a `!` because the compiler just really expects those values to be set if you don't use a `!` or `?` (optional value).

Comment: @critic Thank you for your help. Can I ask one other thing? 
Why we still need to initialize our variables in some classes if we can just set it as optional and leave without init() ?

Comment: Because most of the times you need your class to be in a certain state and enforce that. For example, if you write a class with properties without the `!`, then you ensure that somebody else who might be using this class will have to initialize the class and the mandatory properties with the given parameters. If you were to use the `!` symbol for your properties and the user uses the class with the initializer and not enforce the setting of the properties, it might lead to unexpected behaviour because he has no clue what your intentions were.